# Why is cloud run's container count so much higher than they should be?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, concurrency, google-cloud-run

I have created a new cloud run service set for 50 max requests per second (concurrency), but in production it's been hovering at a max of 2-3 req/s/container. [I know cloud run will aim to keep CPU around 60%](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling), but I've been increasing it from 1 vCPU to 4 vCPU and I'm still not seeing the 1 container I would expect for my load of 0.75 req/s right now. I tried "always allocated" CPU and it didn't reduce the active instance count.

What is going on? Is there any way I can get it to stick to the max I set? It's going to cost hundreds of dollars extra if it keeps scaling like this, since I didn't even turn on all the requests yet.

**Alternative Question**: Since the costs are only only during request allocation, perhaps I'm not charged and the number of active containers doesn't matter?

PS: This is a headless scraper service, so it's going to be running headless chrome which requires a fair amount of CPU to start up, but every additional tab isn't a substantially increased CPU requirement.

PSS: Also, any recommended tips for keeping the container count low is appreciated: I added a min active instance of 1, but that's about all I considered.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There are several factors that may affect Cloud Run concurrency.

- [Maximum concurrent requests per instance (services)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency)

  - Cloud Run provides a maximum concurrent requests per instance setting that specifies the maximum number of requests that can be processed simultaneously by a given container instance.
  - By default each Cloud Run container instance can receive up to 80 requests at the same time; you can increase this to a maximum of 1000. You can [lower the maximum concurrency](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/concurrency) if needed, e.g., your code cannot handle parallel requests, [set concurrency to `1`](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency#concurrency-1).
- [CPU allocation (services)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation)

  - Cloud Run will **only** [scale out](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling) when CPU utilization during request processing *exceeds* 60%.
  - If you select **CPU always allocated** and perform background activities without requests, Cloud Run will not scale out even if CPU usage is over the 60% threshold and in some cases, a container instance might become too busy to accept incoming requests.
- [Maximum number of container instances (services)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/max-instances)

  - Since you've already mentioned that you've set your minimum instance to `1`, it would also a best practice to set a maximum instance so that Cloud Run allows you to limit the scaling of your service in response to incoming requests, although this maximum setting can be exceeded for a brief period due to circumstances such as [traffic spikes](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling#spikes).

These are just some of the factors that could affect concurrency. Hope this helps.